# "Failed to prepare device for development." with Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 16.0 device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to install a xcode project on my iphone X and im getting the error above in the title. Tried adding the device support 16.0 and 16.1 on my xcode devices folder but it still doesn't recognize the phone. Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried turning it(both Xcode, Mac and iPhone) on and off again? 

Comment: Several times. Doesn't work

Comment: Either update xCode (as explained in answer) or copy iPhone 16 device support folder from an xCide 14 to xCode 13.2.1 ( you can find some tutorials about this on SO or Googling around)

Comment: If i could update i wouldn't be opening this thread. I have added the support folder as stated in my main question post and still doesn't work

Comment: You can find an answer [here](https://ryanwise.me/blog/deploy-to-new-devices-xcode/) . As I said, it is just getting the iOS device support for from new xCode (you can download it from Apple support download) and copy it into the xCode you have. It usually work quite well.

Comment: Hi. I have been doing this for the last year. Unfortunately it didnt work for ios 16. The only way i could resolve my issue was by unofficially updating my Mac OS to the latest version and getting xcode 14

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Xcode to version 14. You may need to update your Mac OS version to do so.

Every time Apple releases a new iOS version, they'll release a new Xcode version for developers to work with iOS.

Comment: The only draw back would be the end of support for devices running iOS 10 (eg iPhone 5 - I add to add xCodd 13.4 for this)

Comment: I cant update xcode. Thats the main reason i have posted the fact that i added the fact that i tried with xcode Support files and its still not working for me

Comment: @FnHacks didn't realize you had the constraint of not being able to update Xcode. AFAIK there isn't any other workaround other than to update Xcode...

Comment: The only working solution for me was updating Mac OS to Monterey in an unofficial way through an app called OpenCore. There is a good YouTube video that explains it. Hopefully somebody else that is in the same problem can read this and do the update + fix it by getting the latest xcode 14